# Grouping my data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I hava this table in data base

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7ECj.jpg

I want to group data in this form

------------ **Group 1** -------------

```
1.FoodGroupName : Milk
  a.FoodSubGroup: Milk(type1)
    1.food 1
    2.food 2
    3.food 3
    4.food 4
  b.FoodSubGroup: Milk(type2)
    1.food 1
    2.food 2
    3.food 3
    4.food 4
  c.FoodSubGroup: Milk(type3)
    1.food 1
    2.food 2
    3.food 3
    4.food 4
```

**--------- Group 2 ------------**

```
2.FoodGroupName : Meat
  a.FoodSubGroup: Meat(type1)
    1.food 1
    2.food 2
    3.food 3
    4.food 4
  b.FoodSubGroup: Meat(type2)
    1.food 1
    2.food 2
    3.food 3
    4.food 4
  c.FoodSubGroup: Meat(type3)
    1.food 1
    2.food 2
    3.food 3
    4.food 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT fg.FoodGroupName, fsg.FoodSubGroupName, f.FoodName
FROM FoodGroups fg 
INNER JOIN FoodSubGroups fsg
    ON fg.FoodGroupId = fsg.FoodGroupId
INNER JOIN Foods f
    ON fsg.FoodSubGroupId = f.FoodSubGroupId
ORDER BY fg.FoodGroupName, fsg.FoodSubGroupName, f.FoodName
```

to retrieve data and then output results as you please...

Comment: this should in sql data source but which control in asp.net can do this dynamically and get all foods and food sub groups ordered for a specified food group.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to do that kind of thing :

1) you write a single query that will combines the 3 table (using joins) and return a single dataset (like Marco suggested).

eg :

```
Group         SubGroup    Food
--------------------------------
Meat          Meat1       Food 1
Meat          Meat1       Food 2
Meat          Meat1       Food 3
Meat          Meat2       Food 1
Milk          Milk1       Food 1
Milk          Milk2       Food 1
```

Then by using C# code, you group them.
You can do this using very few lines of code (and efficiently) by using `GroupBy()` linq lambda expression. Have also a look at `ToLookUp()` extension.

If you are not familiar with them, check this page :

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

In the end you should get a collection of objects that allows you to do the following:

```
var groups = ...

foreach(var group in groups)
{  
    //do something with group
    foreach(var subGroup in group.SubGroups)
    {
         //do something with subGroup
         foreach(var food in subGroup.Foods)
         {
            //do something with food
         }
    }
}
```

Then it is very easy to fill a treeview or present data using nested repeaters.

2) you write independent queries that will query each table separately. In the end, you get 3 datasets.

```
Group         
-------
1 Meat
2 Milk

SubGroup
---------
1 1 Meat1
2 1 Meat2
3 2 Milk1
4 2 Milk2

Food
----------
1 1 Food 1
2 1 Food 2
3 1 Food 3
4 2 Food 1
5 3 Food 1
6 4 Food 1
```

Then you use can `Group Join` linq operator to group them.
 In that case, C# will do the joins for you, not sql.

Check here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9/description#groupjoin

In the end you will get same result at 1). Both have advantages / disavantages.